# convert function components to class components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-functional-component, howler.js

I have this class component here

```
class App extends React.Component {
  getHowler() {
    this.player.howler;
  }

  getDuration() {
    this.player.duration();
  }

  getSeek() {
    this.player.seek();
  }

  setSeek() {
    this.player.seek(0.5);
  }
  // This sound file may not work due to cross-origin setting
  render() {
    return (
      <ReactHowler
        src="http://goldfirestudios.com/proj/howlerjs/sound.ogg"
        playing={true}
        ref={(ref) => (this.player = ref)}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I want this to convert into function components. I want to use react howler [seek function](https://github.com/thangngoc89/react-howler#seekseek) in function components. How can I do that? I tried [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) from react and it throws me an error.

The functionality should work like this:
every time I swap the tract it should play from the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const App = () => {
  const player = useRef(null)

  const getHowler = () => {
    player.current.howler;
  }

  const getDuration = () => {
    player.current.duration();
  }

  const getSeek () => {
    player.current.seek();
  }

  const setSeek = () => {
    player.current.seek(0.5);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactHowler
        src="http://goldfirestudios.com/proj/howlerjs/sound.ogg"
        playing={true}
        ref={player}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

- You might need to return asap when `player.current === null`
- You can also wrap the component in the Error boundary component
- If you want to use complete functional component already used in production, feel free to use the package I wrote a package named [atpro-howler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/raptor-howler) which is howler integrated with react via [react-aptor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-aptor)

[image: raptor-howler]

Comment: Thanks, mate. this worked. I missed the `.current` part. That's why it didn't work

Comment: Good to hear that, feel free to use mentioned package, they are completely free, opensource. If you don't mind give me feedback on your use case. If it was helpful full please give us a start on Github, or share the package with your friend :)

Comment: how compatible is this with Next Js?

Comment: I might work like a charm, but let me know if it faced any problem in https://github.com/amirHossein-Ebrahimi/raptor-howler/issues